# Searching Through Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I have these 4 tables:

```
contacts_address (id, owner_id, address)  
contacts (id, name)  
contacts_groups (id, name)  
contacts_groups_link (contact_id, group_id)
```

Each contact has its own row in `contacts`. Each contact can have unlimited address attached to it, therefore `contacts_address` is an address attached to a contact by the 'owner_id' field. The user can also have groups. Each group has a row in `contacts_groups`. When you add a contact to a group it creates an entry in `contacts_groups_link` with that contacts id and that groups id.

I need a query statement where it will search through all contacts in a specific group by name and return those contacts.

I also need a query statement where it will search through all contacts and their attached address in a specific group and return those contacts.

I am so extremely confused on how that would work.

---

Here is the query I use to search through contacts and be able to also search through their addresses:

```
SELECT `contacts_address`.*, `contacts`.*
FROM `contacts` JOIN `contacts_address` ON `contacts_address`.`parent`=`contacts`.`id`
WHERE `contacts`.`owner`='$user_id'
```

Here is the query I use to grab all contacts within a specific group:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts INNER 
JOIN contacts_groups_link ON contacts_groups_link.contact_id = contacts.id 
WHERE contacts_groups_link.group_id='$id'
```

I'm not sure if this would help anyone. I'm so confused on how to combine them.

Comment: I have no idea where to even start. Ill post some of the other MySQL code I have that relates slightly.

Comment: Since this is really a SQL question, I removed the PHP tag. Also, avoid adding stuff like `MySQL:` to the title, instead use the tagging system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

*...search through all contacts in a specific group by name and return those contacts*

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.name
  FROM contacts c JOIN contacts_groups_link l
    ON c.id = l.contact_id JOIN contacts_groups g
    ON l.group_id = g.id
 WHERE g.id = 1 -- << change to appropriate group id
   AND c.name LIKE '%Jhon%' -- << change to other pattern as needed
```

**UPDATED:** *...search through all contacts and their attached address and return those contacts*

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.name
  FROM contacts c JOIN contacts_groups_link l
    ON c.id = l.contact_id JOIN contacts_groups g
    ON l.group_id = g.id JOIN contacts_address a
    ON c.id = a.owner_id
 WHERE g.id = 1 -- << change to appropriate group id
   AND a.address LIKE '%Main St.%' -- << change to other pattern as needed
 GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Comment: Crap I'm sorry. The first one is exactly what I want but the second one I forgot something in the description of what I needed. '...search through all contacts and their attached address IN A SPECIFIC GROUP and return those contacts'